# Establishing inheritance and overriding in OCaml class types

Tags: class, inheritance, ocaml

I'm trying to write class types and having an issue expressing what I want.

I have

```
class type event_emitter = object
   method on : string -> unit
end
```

and then I want to do this:

```
class type socket = object
    inherit event_emitter
    method on : int -> unit
end
```

But I get a compiler error about a type signature mismatch between the two. I've also tried using the `virtual` keyword, doing `class type virtual event_emitter = method virtual on : string -> unit` but this also doesn't work as I guess these are class type definitions, not implementations anyway.

I really want this method override to work and this seemed straightforward, not sure why its not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is *overloading*, not *overriding*. You are trying to create a new method in `socket` with the same name as in `event_emitter`, but with a different type. Overriding would be creating a new method with the same name and type. This description would hold for other languages like Java and C++, as well. The difference is that I don't believe OCaml allows this kind of overloading – the same as for regular functions.

Note that if you entered the analogous declarations for Java, it would work, but `socket` would have two `on` methods, not one. OCaml doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't contradict antron's answer, but you can do this:

```
class type ['a] event_emitter = object
   method on : 'a -> unit
end

class type socket = object
    inherit [int] event_emitter
end
```

Comment: Great, will try this.